# IE Error while executing the nodeJS script

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, wdio-v5

The application which I am automating is supportable on IE browser. After writing my script in feature and the step definition ; while I am trying to execute my script the console is throwing below error -

```
ERROR: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'W10-VDI-WDW4435', ip: '10.201.110.181', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
```

Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace:
internetexplorer[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sure Rob.. that i kept for the better understanding , i will keep in mind . Thankx

Comment: Hi @swagatika Is there any update about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you posted, I think the issue is that you didn't set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value in IE 11.

To set the Protected Mode settings, choose **Internet Options** from the **Tools** menu, and click on the **Security** tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled **Enable Protected Mode**. Please make sure the setting for each zone has the same value (all checked or all unchecked).

Besides, you also need to meet all these [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) when automating IE 11.

[image]